# Checking spent time for an action using logs

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

The question is something that we all have faced:

How can I check and see how log my action/method has taken?

Of course one way is to have a stopwatch and start it before you start the action and stopping it after you are done like this:

```
...
logger.Debug("Starting action Blah Blah");
var sw = new StopWatch();
sw.Start();

..
//Doing the action
..
sw.Stop();
logger.Debug($"action Blah Blah spent {sw.Elapsed}");
```

Right?

Isn't there an easier way to do it without adding logging logic to my code?

Comment: Other than having the Stopwatch outside, so it doesn't have to be re-created all the time, nothing wrong with using it as far as i can tell.

Comment: When using a logger, usually my log layout looks like this: `"${time}: ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"`. If you use something similar, you probably won't need any additional time calculations as your log  would display something like: *"05:18:01.3595: Performing MyAction"* and *"05:18:02.7899: MyAction completed"*.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that we use is to add a custom filter to the MVC application.

LogActionFilter

```
public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static NLog.Logger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _logger.Trace("{0} Controller: {1}, Action: {2}",
                      MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                      filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
                      filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        _logger.Trace("{0} Controller: {1}, Action: {2}",
                      MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                      filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
                      filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName));
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then in your `FilterConfig`;

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new LogActionFilter());
    }
}
```

The example above logs the times but you can tweak this to do other things with the timing as needed.

Comment: I'm very tired, but what part of this code logs the time?

Comment: Simply create a class that does what you want. This comment explains what you want if I understand correctly.

Comment: @RufusL in the example above I'm logging via NLog. In its configuration, a call to `Trace` logs the time automatically. In your case, you'd track the time via an instance of `StopWatch`, or whatever you need.